# Can we have a grid inside the cell of the DataGrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, grid

I require to have a DataGrid having multiple rows and 3 columns. Now each cell of the DataGrid is to show some information (6 to 8 parameters) and a button. On click of this button a pop-up is to be shown.

Now for displaying the data inside the cell of the DataGrid, I need to align them properly and was thinking of using the Grid. How to achieve this.

Also how do I get to know at the click event of the button that which cell button was clicked ?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 5):

You may add DataGridTemplateColumn(s) to your DataGrid, and then define usual data template for the column:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Foo" Width="SizeToCells">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                       ...
                      <Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>  
<DataGrid.Columns>
```

Now about the click event. Bind your grid with items source. Each item in that source  must be a view model with any ICommand property. Bind this property to the button's command in cell template, and you will get it.